# Correction script Bash

Tags: bash, dns

I'm trying in vain to solve my problem with this script.

```
#!/bin/bash
for a in `wget -O - "https://pastebin.com/raw/7BFC94Ty"`; do echo "local-zone: \""$a" redirect\"""local-data: \""$a" A 0.0.0.0\"" >> adstest.conf; done
```

Here is the result

```
local-zone: "101com.com
 redirect"local-data: "101com.com
 A 0.0.0.0"
```

But this is not the right formatting, this is the expected result:

```
local-zone: "101com.com" redirect
local-data: "101com.com A 0.0.0.0"
```

But I can not find this damn solution. I'm also looking for a solution to be able to use a local file rather than a url because I have a file of 40 000 lines and I would like to do without a web host for that.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: learn to use the `printf` cmd, either from cmd-line, or as part of `awk`. See http://grymoire.com/Unix/awk.html and search for printf for reasonable introduction. And if you search here with `[awk] printf` you'll find 6000+ Q/A that should help illustrate the usage. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to run it through `dos2unix` to get rid of the Windoze line breaks, then do two separate `echo`s and send the results of the entire loop to the output file:

```
for a in `wget -O - "https://pastebin.com/raw/7BFC94Ty" | dos2unix`; do
  echo 'local-zone: "'$a'" redirect'
  echo 'local-data: "'$a' A 0.0.0.0"'
done >> adstest.conf
```

I also used single-quotes so I did not have to escape the doubles you want printed.

Sample results:

```
$ rm adstest.conf 

$ for a in `wget -O - "https://pastebin.com/raw/7BFC94Ty" | dos2unix`; do   echo 'local-zone: "'$a'" redirect';   echo 'local-data: "'$a' A 0.0.0.0"'; done >> adstest.conf
--2017-07-07 14:12:07--  https://pastebin.com/raw/7BFC94Ty
Resolving pastebin.com (pastebin.com)... 104.20.208.21, 104.20.209.21
Connecting to pastebin.com (pastebin.com)|104.20.208.21|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

-                                        [ <=>                                                                   ] 385.23K  --.-KB/s    in 0.09s   

2017-07-07 14:12:07 (3.97 MB/s) - written to stdout [394475]

$ wc -l adstest.conf 
41860 adstest.conf

$ head adstest.conf 
local-zone: "101com.com" redirect
local-data: "101com.com A 0.0.0.0"
local-zone: "101order.com" redirect
local-data: "101order.com A 0.0.0.0"
local-zone: "123found.com" redirect
local-data: "123found.com A 0.0.0.0"
local-zone: "140proof.com" redirect
local-data: "140proof.com A 0.0.0.0"
local-zone: "180hits.de" redirect
local-data: "180hits.de A 0.0.0.0"
```

Comment: Please don't perpetuate the use of `for a in $(...)`; it's a bug that should be fixed. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: I endeavored to make the fewest possible changes to his code.  Since spaces are not allowed in URL's, there can be no spaces in the output of this `wget`. Thus, this it will work just fine because he is not reading lines, but words.  The words just happen to be on separate lines.

Comment: I just ran a test and it seems to have a problem, the output file is well created but it is empty.

Comment: I just copied those lines above, copied it into my shell, and got a 41860-line file.  I'll append results.

Comment: URLs *can* contain `?`, though, which left unquoted will be treated as a pattern, which depending on your settings could either cause an error or be silently ignored.

Comment: This is good for me to use locally and not using a url, to avoid the kinds of problems.

Comment: A `?` is not valid in a hostname.  These are hostnames.

Comment: In this case, it would be necessary to erase all the lines relating to a '?' But for the script you told me @Jack, it works perfectly !

Comment: Happy to help!  That's why we're here!

Comment: It only remains to get it to work with a local file on the computer but I think that can already work very well (if I can find a host for a file of more than 40 000 lines ). But thank you for your help !

Comment: You can drive @chepner nuts by replacing the `wget` with `cat 7BFC94Ty`. :)

Answer (score 1):

To address @chepner's concerns, we can use `sed` to process the stream:

```
wget -O - "https://pastebin.com/raw/7BFC94Ty" | dos2unix | sed 's/\(.*\)/local-zone: "\1" redirect\nlocal-data: "\1 A 0.0.0.0"/' > adstest.conf
```

It just takes the whole pattern space of the line, saved with `\(.*\)`, and replaces it with the text we want, putting the pattern space back in with `\1` where we need it, and using `\n` to put in the line break.